# Quotes issue with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, quotes

I need help to fix syntax errors with this string:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[computer_tablet]<a href="URL" class="btn btn-blue" style="margin-left: 6px;" onclick="javascript:void window.open('URL','1372423739702','width=300,height=320,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');return false;">Words</a>[/computer_tablet]'); ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: This is not a complete (or even functionally incomplete) code snippet.

Comment: I think that "total noob" is a important detail for users that would help me

Comment: It isn't. We can tell what skill level you are at based on the code and the question, but it truly isn't important. People are here to help out and answer questions, either by noobs or by experts. If someone knows the answer, they'll tell you. You've got 2 correct answers right now.

Comment: Check out the documentation, too: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php -- it discusses this topic in pretty good detail there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same quotes as part of the parameter string as you are using to define the start and end of the string. Hence, when the code compiles, the string starts at "`[computer...`" and ends at "`windows.open(`". You need to use escape quotes - `\'` - whenever you use the same quotes that you start and end your string with.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[computer_tablet]<a href="URL" class="btn btn-blue" style="margin-left: 6px;" onclick="javascript:void window.open(\'URL\',\'1372423739702\',\'width=300,height=320,toolbar=0,menubar=0‌​,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,left=0,top=0\');return false;">Words</a>[/computer_tablet]'); ?>
```

Notice the backslash before each single quote?

Comment: I can't get it working, could you give me the full correct code please? Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer, that should work :)

Comment: Hi, your code works, thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`window.open(\'URL\', \'etc...`
Escape quotes

Comment: I can't get it working, could you give me the full correct code please? Thank you so much

Comment: Well you should learn a language's syntax before using it, and even more when mixing several languages together.